# Get Map value from Firebase java

Tags: java, android, firebase

I would like to as you with support.

**In Firebase I have document with this hierarchy**:

Firebase hierarchy:
[image: Firebase hierarchy]

In Firebasehandler.java I receive the data from :

```
for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : queryDocumentSnapshots) {

   String title = DocumentSnapshot.get(ARG_Firebase_Offer_Title).toString();
   Timestamp dateStartCruise = documentSnapshot.getTimestamp(ARG_Firebase_Offer_DateStartCruise);
   Long numberOfCrew = documentSnapshot.getLong(ARG_Firebase_Offer_MaxNumberCrew);
}
```

It is working for Long, String and others. Unfortunately I don't know how to receive data from Firebase in format ***Map***.

Thank you very much all for support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DocumentSnapshot's `get()` method will return a `Map<String, Object>` when the document field is an object.  Simply cast it to that type.

Comment: I have impelemted it and its work! Thank you very much

`Map<String,Boolean> language = new HashMap<>();
                            language = (Map<String, Boolean>) documentSnapshot.get(ARG_Firebase_Offer_Language);`